# in uat js changes are done but in browser it is not reflecting

Tags: magento2, cache

i tried
cntrl + shit + R

below commands i ran

```
 sudo rm -rf var/ generated/ pub/static/frontend 
 pub/static/adminhtml pub/static/deployed_version.txt
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_BE fr_BE -f
 sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

i am in developer mode also

Comment: try to clear browser cache

Comment: @RkRathod - i have clear browser cache also .. When i had ?sometext in url then js file get refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable signing of static files.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html

Comment: i enabled Static File Settings but still not reflecting

Comment: Just to be sure: after enabling, 1. flush full page cache 2. do setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: thank you so much.. after clearing cache it got worked